# Better way to traverse this DOM segment

Tags: jquery, dom, traversal

Is there a better way than traversing like this?:

```
$('#part'+rowNumber).parent().parent().next().children('input').val(manufacturer);
```

The DOM segment in question is:

```
var html = '<div class="row-fluid">';
    html += '<div class="span1"><img title="Remove part." class="pull-right remove-part" width="20px" src="http://www.view.com/public_html/images/icons/minus.png"></div>';
    html += '<div class="span1"><input type="number" value="1" class="span12"/></div>';
    html += '<div class="span5"><input id="part'+rowNumber+'" type="text" class="span12"/></div>';
    html += '<div class="span4"><input type="text" class="span12 last"/></div>';
    html += '<div class="span1"></div>';
    html += '</div>';
```

Comment: try this
$('#part'+rowNumber).parents().eq(1).next().children('input').val(manufacturer);

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .parent().parent(), try [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), other than that I don't see anything else

```
$('#part'+rowNumber).closest('.row-fluid').next().children('input').val(manufacturer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write like:

```
$('#part'+rowNumber).parents('.row-fluid').next().children('input').val(manufacturer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using .closest() selector: 
        $('#part'+rowNumber).closest('.row-fluid').next().find('input').val(manufacturer);